# Finding substring within string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find a specific string within a string.
For example, let's say I have the string

`string = "username:quantopia;password:blabla`

How can I then find `quantopia`?
I am using python 3.

Update: I am sorry I did not mention what I try before..

```
string.split('username:',1)[1].split(';',1)[0]
```

But this look very bad and not efficient, I was hoping for something better.

Comment: Hey I can see you're new here but, this is already referenced everywhere in SO....

Comment: this is common task am sur if you google it you will find loads of examples. but even if its not, you should at least show some effort at trying to solve the problem yourself

Comment: hi sorry sorry I'm couldn't find it!!! and I try split but it did not look like a good solution! I will edit the question and include what I try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regex as such:

```
import re

username = re.search("username:(.*);password", "username:quantopia;password:blabla").group(1)
print("username:", username)
```

This will output `quantopia`.

In this expression `"username:(.*);password"` you are saying "give me everything from `username:` to `;password`" So this is why you're getting `quantopia`. This might as well be `":(.*);"` as it will output the same thing in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't an `if` and `in` work as well, and be much simpler?

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova What do you mean? I think the question refers to extracting "quantopia", the substring from the main string. If so, no `if in` would not be enough.

Comment: I get what you mean @sansa, i think the issue here is the OP doesnt specify if he knows the substring he wants to find or if he wants to find the string after username etc. Thats why its good to ask questions in the comments if its unclear what the OP is asking

Comment: The OP states *I want to find a specific string within a string*, and nothing else. I thought he had the string ahead of time and wanted to test if it existed in another string.

Comment: I'm surprise this question hasn't been closed at a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is:

```
string = "username:quantopia;password:blabla"
username = "username"

if username in string:
   # do work.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better to just use split to create a dictionary so you dont need to use multiple regex to extract different parts of data sets. The below will split stirng into key value pairs then split key value pairs then pass the list of lists to dict to create a dictionary.

```py
string = "username:quantopia;password:blabla"
data = dict([pairs.split(':') for pairs in string.split(';')])
print(f'username is "{data["username"]}" and password is "{data["password"]}"')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
username is "quantopia" and password is "blabla"
```